# How to get self join type result in solr for find out dulicate result

Tags: sql, solr, solaris

I need to find duplicate records in solr. I have used `facets` and `facet.pivot` to get duplicate results. It is working to some extent.

My scenario:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
fname    | lname    |nationality1 | nationality2 | nationality3
---------------------------------------------------------------
vishal   | varshney | IND         | AUS          | USA
---------------------------------------------------------------
Varshney | vishal   | CAN         | IND          | BRB
--------------------------------------------------------------
vis      | var      | TCM         | ABC          | IND
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to fetch all three results in SOLR. How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770034/finding-duplicate-field-values-in-solr

Comment: @mohan111 As i have already mention, i have used pivot. It would be better if you write the actual query, thanks

Comment: So what are the duplicate values you're trying to match? I don't understand where the duplication occurs.

Comment: @MatsLindh you can see in above example that all three rows have one common nationality that is `IND`. So i want the query which can fetch these type of results.

Comment: And query should be generic not specifically for `IND`.

Comment: OK - so find documents that have a value common in _any_ of the three fields?

Comment: yes, but not a particular value, it would be any value that is repeating.